# How to set path permently for fdisk command

Tags: shell, path

I am using Debian 10 on my laptop. I am facing an error message:

```
# fdisk -l
bash: fdisk: command not found
```

My path is:

```
test@debian:/sbin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games</code>
```

If I set my `$PATH` to:

```
test@debian:/$ PATH="/sbin:$PATH"
```

I then get:

```
test@debian:/$ echo $PATH
/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

After that my `fdisk -l` command executes perfectly. The problem is that every time I reboot my laptop, I have to set the path again. I want to  add it permanently.

Please guide me on which file may I choose to edit for permanent changes and what should I add inside it.

Comment: Please see the answers to the duplicate. Basically, you just add `PATH="/sbin:$PATH"` to the end of your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: Please guide me  the exact file and the location in which I may add my path . In the answer still it is not clear.
 test@debian:/$ PATH="/sbin:$PATH"

Comment: Just open the file `~/.profile` in a text editor (create it if it doesn't exist) and add a line with `PATH="/sbin:$PATH"` to that file. Save the file, log out, log back in and it should be ready.

Comment: I try to follow the instructions but failed.  <code># if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
#    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH";PATH="/sbin:$PATH"
        PATH="/sbin:$PATH"
fi </code>

Comment: Please just do as I suggested. Just open the file `~/.profile`,  a line with PATH="/sbin:$PATH"`, save the file and log out.